# I have two lists in Checkbox,One I have already checked One is not checked initially

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, checkbox

I want to make a list of all checked values in the checkbox if I check somwething from xyz it should be pushed in a list If i uncheck something from list xyz and template,It should be pulled from a list

{{item}}

{{item}}

Comment: What have you done so far? Please show some code that you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `(change)` handler to push and remove items from array.

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items">
  <input 
    type="checkbox" 
    name="{{item}}" 
    (change)="$event.target.checked ? selected.push(item) : selected.splice(selected.indexOf(item),1)">
  {{item}}
</div>
```

Demo : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hpdg3h

Answer (score 0):

I have created two Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qfxe3j

Out of which below is the simplest one, without any functional code.

menu.component.html

```
<div style="display: inline-flex;">
  <div style="padding: 5px;border: 1px solid;margin-left: 30px;width: 120px;height: 200px;">
    <p>list 1</p>
    <ul style="list-style: none;">
      <ng-container *ngFor="let i of list">
        <li *ngIf="!i.checked">
          <input type="checkbox" [name]="i.val" [id]="i.val" [checked]="i.checked" (change)="i.checked = !i.checked">
          <label [for]="i.val">item {{i.val}}</label>
        </li>
      </ng-container>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div style="padding: 5px;border: 1px solid;margin-left: 30px;width: 120px;height: 200px;">
    <p>list 2</p>
    <ul style="list-style: none;">
        <ng-container *ngFor="let i of list">
          <li *ngIf="i.checked">
            <input type="checkbox" [name]="i.val" [id]="i.val" [checked]="i.checked" (change)="i.checked = !i.checked">
            <label [for]="i.val">item {{i.val}}</label>
          </li>
        </ng-container>
      </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

menu.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-menu',
  templateUrl: './menu.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./menu.component.scss']
})
export class MenuComponent implements OnInit {
  list:any = [
    {val: 1, checked: false},
    {val: 2, checked: false},
    {val: 3, checked: false},
    {val: 4, checked: false},
    {val: 4, checked: false}
  ];
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```